# android notification banner not displaying

Tags: java, android

for some reason when I make a notification appear on my app in will vibrate and make noise but no banner appears across the top of the phone.  Is there a specific command I need to make it do this?

```
public Notification getNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(serviceContext,     NotificationGenerator.class); //not sure how
        // this class i pass matters
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(serviceContext, 0, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new     NotificationCompat.Builder(serviceContext)
            .setContentTitle(message)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.dominos_icon)
            .setContentIntent(pi);
        Notification n = builder.build();
        n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        return n;
    }
```

Comment: Please include the code you use to generate the Notification.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Just added it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine once you will add the lines below:

```
NotificationManager n_mngr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
n_mngr.notify(NOTIF_ID, n);
```

Comment: I'm actually passing the notification out of the function and making a foreground notification.    startForeground(notifID, notification);